# TortoiseSVN actions aren't appearing in the context menu after installing them

Tags: tortoisesvn

Using Windows 7 Ultimate on 64bits. Why isn't it showing? I can find tortoise svn in the start menu and when I launch it it says the application is a shell extension but it doesn't show.

I just installed this at work this morning and now I want to install it at home. Any help? Why won't it show? I have already rebooted my machine.

Comment: Only the 32Bit version - do I need the 64 as well?

Comment: @Sergio yup, because Explorer is 64 bit in 64 bit Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you install the 64-bit version?

You need 64 bit TortoiseSVN on 64 bit Windows because otherwise, its Explorer won't "see" Tortoise.

The best thing is actually to [install both](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads) to make sure Tortoise works in the folder views of 32-Bit applications like IDE's, too.

> Note that x64 users can install both the 32 and 64-bit versions side by side. This will enable the TortoiseSVN features also for 32-bit applications.

If you get the TortoiseSVN specific commands when right-clicking a file or folder in Explorer, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Did you reboot? You need to restart explorer.exe

Comment: Doesn't really deserve a downvote IMO, as it's correct, although it might be better off as a comment. +1 to even out

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN is a shell extension and not a regular desktop application like WinCVS. All commands are available from the Context menu. I suggest be first familiar with svn commands and how they work and then try to use the same commands through TortoiseSVN.